# Find index of closest number in sorted array C++

Tags: c++, sorting

For example I have an sorted array

```
{1,10,11,17,34,72,64}
```

and if give number 12 it returns 1

```
int closest_val(vector<int> vals, int digit)
{
...
}

closest_val({1,11,10,17,34,72,64}, 12)

Output: 2
```

Comment: Your array is not sorted, `11 > 10`. What is your question or problem?

Comment: What have you tried? If not yet, you need `std::lower_bound` with custom comparator. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound

Comment: use binary search

Comment: *"if give number 12 it returns 1"*, as I understand it should return 2 (as 11 is the closest number). As you have shown no code...

Comment: @sorry my bad. I want a code that do it for me.Can you help

Comment: @mch I want a function that do it for me

Comment: That's not how this site works. Give it a try and show us your code, then we might help you with that.